# Discrepancy in floats between NumPy and Clojure/Java

Tags: clojure, floating-point, numpy, endianness

Does anyone have any advice on how to read float values out of a binary file using java or clojure? I'm comparing my current values to the result of Python's NumPy's `nump.fromfile('path', dtype="f")` method, and I'm simply not getting the same answer. I suspect that this is because Java's `DataInputStream.readFloat()` method assumes that the binary file was written by java, as [this documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readFloat%28%29) shows:

> Reads four input bytes and returns a
>   float value. It does this by first
>   constructing an int value in exactly
>   the manner of the readInt method, then
>   converting this int value to a float
>   in exactly the manner of the method
>   Float.intBitsToFloat. This method is
>   suitable for reading bytes written by
>   the writeFloat method of interface
>   DataOutput.

So, I think java is reading the float values in backwards. The first twelve bytes are:

```
(0 -64 121 -60 0 -64 121 -60 0 -64 121 -60)
```

Clojure/java sees this as repeated `1.7676097E-38`, while NumPy and Python see it as repeated `-999.0`. For reference, I'm using [this dataset](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.NOAA/.NCEP/.CPC/.PRECL/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java uses "network order" (big endian) in java.io. However java.nio lets you choose which endianness to apply:

```
user=> (-> (map byte [0 -64 121 -60]) byte-array java.nio.ByteBuffer/wrap 
         (.order java.nio.ByteOrder/LITTLE_ENDIAN) .getFloat)
-999.0
```

The next step for you is either to read the whole file in a byte array or to create a `FileChannel` from a `FileInputStream`, then mmap it and read from the resulting mmaped `ByteBuffer` using `.getFloat`.

Comment: cgrand, this works wonderfully. I now have a ByteBuffer that gives me access to the file -- the next question is, how to treat the bytebuffer as a 3d matrix?

Comment: Sparse or not? Read-only, persistent or mutable?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that data set is available in netCDF format. There are netCDF libraries for both python+numpy and java. Those libraries will solve pretty much all of your portability issues and probably not have much of an impact on performance.

Saving numbers to a file is pretty much a solved problem. You shouldn't have to work at a level where endianness matters unless you are doing it for fun.

Comment: hey, my link to the data was misleading -- the dataset I referenced was the 2.5 degree data, while I was actually trying to open the 0.5 degree data, which is only available in binary: ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/50yr/gauge/0.5deg/

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file as bytes, change the endian, write those bytes to an in-memory stream and then use the DataInputStream again to read them in as floats.